# No module named numpy when using child_process spawn in node.js express

Tags: python, node.js, express, child-process

I'm trying to run a python script with an input and an output when the user submits a form.
The form activates the post function in express and I have used spawn of child_process to run the script. However, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy' happens.

This is my index.js code.

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
router.post('/testing', function (req, res) {
//res.send('POST request to the homepage')
const pythonProcess = spawn('python', ["./public/models/main.py", [1, 2, 3]]);
let output;
pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    // Do something with the data returned from python script
    output+=data;
});

pythonProcess.on("end", () => {
    console.log(output.toString())
    res.write(output);

})

pythonProcess.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
    console.error(data.toString())
})
})
```

and this is my python code

```
import sys
import numpy as np


def multiply_matrix(matrix):
    return matrix * 2


def main():
    matrix = multiply_matrix(sys.argv[1])
    print(matrix)
    sys.stdout.flush()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

How can I fix this?
I need this to develop a larger program with more complicated computations using python.

Comment: Command line arguments are always passed as strings.  I have no idea what Javscript is doing with `[1,2,3]`.  Have you tried just printing the contents of `sys.argv` and returning?

Comment: @TimRoberts I found out that the no module error was because I didn't have numpy installed in my python. I changed the argument as strings and tried printing sys.argv[1] but infinite loading occurs.